# Usually how do developers test the robustness/reliability of an Ethereum client?

Tags: go-ethereum

The Ethereum blockchain is the operational backbone of major decentralized finance platforms. As such, an Ethereum client is expected to be exceptionally reliable. I am curious about how developers test the reliability of an Ethereum client.

I would also like to share the recent paper on this topic: Chaos Engineering of Ethereum Blockchain Clients, https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.00221

Abstract:

The Ethereum blockchain is the operational backbone of major decentralized finance platforms. As such, it is expected to be exceptionally reliable. In this paper, we present ChaosETH, a chaos engineering tool for resilience assessment of Ethereum clients. ChaosETH operates in the following manner: First, it monitors Ethereum clients to determine their normal behavior. Then, it injects system call invocation errors into the Ethereum clients and observes the resulting behavior under perturbation. Finally, ChaosETH compares the behavior recorded before, during, and after perturbation to assess the impact of the injected system call invocation errors. The experiments are performed on the two most popular Ethereum client implementations: GoEthereum and OpenEthereum. We experiment with 22 different types of system call invocation errors. We assess their impact on the Ethereum clients with respect to 15 application-level metrics. Our results reveal a broad spectrum of resilience characteristics of Ethereum clients in the presence of system call invocation errors, ranging from direct crashes to full resilience. The experiments clearly demonstrate the feasibility of applying chaos engineering principles to blockchains.

Comment: There's this project https://github.com/ethereum/tests. The idea sound interesting probably you should ask the Ethereum Foundation if they are interested in more testing tools, perhaps you could apply for a grant.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael for the comment! Yes, I am aware of this github repo, as well as the [retesteth](https://github.com/ethereum/retesteth) project. For me the projects focus more on providing comprehensive unit/integration test cases for an Ethereum client implementation. Production testing or chaos engineering might be helpful to improve a client's resilience. Thank you for the suggestion. I am also considering to reach out to the Ethereum Foundation :)